# ¿Como convertir de Word a PDF en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dompdf, phpword

Estoy ocupando PhpWord para crear rellenar una plantilla, eso ya lo realiza bien pero ahora quiero convertirlo a PDF pero ya intentado de muchas maneras y ya me desespere:

Aun ocupando DomPDF y TCPDF siempre caigo en este error:

```
PDF rendering library or library path has not been defined.
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar a resolver este problema.

**FileWordController.php (Laravel)**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FileWordController extends Controller
{
    public function crearWordDocx(){
        $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor(Storage_path('template.docx'));
        $title = "Warehouse";
        $templateProcessor->setValue('title_company',$title);
        $templateProcessor->saveAs('Document02.docx');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Document02.docx; charset=iso-8859-1");
        echo file_get_contents("Document02.docx");
    }
}
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/233/how-to-generate-a-pdf-from-html-with-tcpdf-in-laravel

Comment: @DiegoAvila ¿y eso que tiene que ver con PHPWord?

Comment: Pregunta: como añades en tu documento .docx la variable 'title_company'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define la ruta y el nombre de la biblioteca encargada directamente en la configuración de PHPWord:

```
    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

    $domPdfPath = realpath('../vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');
    \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath);
```